# What does 而 mean in 因森发·加计学院问题而曝光率增高的?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word

In the following sentence:

> 因森发·加计学院问题**而**曝光率增高的「sontaku」一词，也已经成为了日常用语。

I know the use of 而 as "and", but I feel it doesn't make sense here to use 而, since I don't understand what it connects.

So how does 而 work here? Also, is my understanding correct that 而 here doesn't express "and"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`而` is not used as `and` here, but `as a result;with the result that;thus`.

**因A而B** is a common usage; `因` is used to emphasize that *A* is the cause, `而` is used to represent that *B* is the result.

You can also use `因为` or `由于` instead of `因` in this usage.

Comment: Thanks and that makes sense! Is there any other pattern except 因 in this usage?

Comment: @Blaszard You can also use `因为` or `由于` instead of `因`.